# Drawing a circle on the current window that moves (Python)

Tags: python, graphics

I'm facing a problem with python.
i want to draw on my monitor a circle, that can move around.

let's say i have my browser open, i want to be able to make the circle go around on his own AND be able to use the mouse to press any button i want.

the idea is that the circle is connected to my hands movement thanks to Leap Motion, and i want to display the gestures i make while being able to use the mouse.

my worries are that i have to make a trasparent window which doesn't let me to use the mouse because i would clik on the trasparent window.

Thanks!

Comment: What graphics package are you using?

Comment: i have yet to decide, i don't know which one is better for what i'm doing

Comment: Ok, because the answer to your question would depend on that. I recommend [pygame](http://pygame.org). It is fairly easy to use and I believe you would be able to do what you want with it.

Comment: I can't figure out how to make the trasparent window untouchable ( which means that touching on the window will make the window below react to the click and not the trasparent window) so i figured that would be better to make a little window that moves around my screen so i'm always able to touch somewhere else on the screen
pygame seems to not allow me to move the window though.

Comment: Have you tried using surfaces?

Comment: i've seen people trying to get a trasparent window using pygame, but they said it wasn't the right solution, i'm actually trying with gtk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, i used wxPython

Down below the code:

```
    import wx, inspect, os, sys, win32gui

IMAGE_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe()))) + '\cerchio.png'


class Cursor(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, log):
        self.log = log
        self.delta = wx.Point(0,0)
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "Shaped Window",
                                style =
                                wx.FRAME_SHAPED
                                | wx.SIMPLE_BORDER
                                | wx.FRAME_NO_TASKBAR
                                | wx.STAY_ON_TOP
                                )


        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER,         self.update, self.timer)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT,         self.OnPaint)

        self.x=0
        self.y=0
        self.hasShape = False
        self.SetClientSize( (50, 50) )
        image = wx.Image(IMAGE_PATH, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
        image.SetMaskColour(255,255,255)
        image.SetMask(True)            
        self.bmp = wx.BitmapFromImage(image)

        self.SetWindowShape()
        self.timer.Start(1)
        dc = wx.ClientDC(self)

        dc.DrawBitmap(self.bmp, 0, 0, True)


    def OnExit(self, evt):
        self.Close()

    def SetWindowShape(self, *evt):
        # Use the bitmap's mask to determine the region
        r = wx.RegionFromBitmap(self.bmp)
        self.hasShape = self.SetShape(r)

    def OnPaint(self, evt):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        dc.DrawBitmap(self.bmp, 0, 0, True)


    def OnExit(self, evt):
        self.Close()

    def update(self, event):
        #self.x, self.y = win32gui.GetCursorPos()
        self.SetPosition((self.x,self.y))



if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = wx.App( False )
    frm = Cursor(None, -1)
    frm.Show()



    app.MainLoop()
```

This maps 50x50 png image with white background (modify IMAGE_PATH) to the cursor position (you won't be able to click though)